# PDF vector images in iOS. Why does having a smaller image result in jagged edges?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, vector-graphics

I want to use pdf vector images in my app, I don't totally understand how it works though. I understand that a PDF file can be resized to any size and it will retain quality. I have a very large PDF image (a cartoon/sticker for a chat app) and it looks perfectly smooth at a medium size on screen. If I start to go smaller though, say thumbnail size the black outline starts to look jagged. Why does this happen? I thought the images could be resized without quality loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when programatically changing the UIImageView's `centre`.

The result of this can lead to pixel misalignment of your view. I.e. the x or y of the frame's origin (or width or height of the frame's size) may lie on a non integral value, such as x = 10.5, where it will display correctly if x = 10.

Rendering views positioned a fraction into a full pixel will result with jagged lines, I think its related to aliasing.

Therefore wrap the CGRect of the frame with `CGRectIntegral()` to convert your frame's origin and size values to integers.

Example (Swift):

```
imageView?.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100))
```

See the Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntegral